# Отслеживать включение

Tags: android

Есть ли какой-либо бродкаст ресивер, чтобы отследить включение устройства?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то типа [этого](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)?

Answer (score 1):

Включение устройства или включение экрана?

```
ACTION_SCREEN_ON
BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION
```